# Can't enter wired weight paint in 2.81

Tags: weight-painting, wireframe

I can't go to wired weight paint mode, i want to weight paint in wired mode instead of solid, but it wont let me go there, it goes full wired instead of weight paint mode.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, the toggle x-ray option was toggled on and you need to toggle that option off before going to weight painting.